# Organic Groups: Audience field is missing

Tags: organic-groups

I seem to have a problem with Organic Groups. I follow the instructions by the book but when I want to create content the audience label and field is missing! Thus I can't select the group to which the content is visible.

This in contrast to the settings where it is stated that it must appear... .

All my permissions seem right.

Does anybody have a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the field to the content type.  Configuration>OG field settings.  In Bundles, select Node>Group Content (or whatever your group content type is called).  Then in Fields, choose Groups Audience.  Then click the Add field button.